# The logo align well with the navbar. And the things I add later always start from top

Tags: html, css

This is the code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
}

#nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(196, 14, 14);
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

ul li.active a {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.logo img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  display: inline;
}

.logo {}

.main {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.form-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 49%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.title h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Landing Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <header id="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <img id="header-img" src="images/logo.png" alt="A tree">
      </div>
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href>Details</a></li>
          <li><a href>About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="title">
        <h1>THE GAZETTE</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="form-div">
        <form id="form">
          <input type="email" required id="email" placeholder="Please enter your email adress" size="30">
          <input type="submit" id="submit">
        </form>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur atque nesciunt nam porro corporis dicta officiis asperiores officia, deleniti vitae. Ipsa dolorum minima voluptatem ex corporis laboriosam veritatis mollitia eum.</p>


  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

So when I change the .logo img top 3em or 4em the logo no longer be cropped. But it doesn't align with the nav-bar so it becomes a little farther from the top.
The other problem is because I made * margin, padding 0 all the things I add later go on top and I have to  adjust them. How can I make it so it will continue to scroll down.

Comment: where is the css of the header id?

Comment: I added now to put a background image. 
Now it looks like this: 'background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;'

Comment: I don't uderstand what you really want do you want the image and the nav bar be in the same line or what?